# Long layover at Charles de Gaulle airport

Tags: airports, layovers, cdg

I have a 23 hours layover at Charles de Gaulle airport in Paris. I don't have a Schengen visa. Any advice for a bit of comfort.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179983/meet-a-friend-while-in-transit-at-the-airport

Answer (score 8):

The terminal where you well spent these 23h might be relevant here. I once had a layover in a terminal where planes from Morocco and Thailand boarded. I forgot which terminal that was. If you are stuck in the same terminal and you are not able to check in into one of the [hotels](http://www.novotel.com/nl/hotel-1014-novotel-paris-cdg-terminal/index.shtml) you are up for a rough ride.

There was not much amusement around and only a handful of shops. In terms of comfort you had the choice between the floor and the default benches you see on almost any gate worldwide.

While you are there You could  read the autobiography of [Mehran Karimi Nasseri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri). It is he, who inspired hollywood for the film [The terminal](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0362227/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). From his perspective 23h is peanuts. Reading that book, while you are actually stuck at CDG would add a special touch.

Comment: Very inspired and philosophical answer, thanx

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Do you know if it is possible to meet a friend at the Airport in transit? (I'm asking about this here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179983/meet-a-friend-while-in-transit-at-the-airport).