# A place to sleep during a 13-hour layover in Charles-De-Gaulle airport?

Tags: layovers, sleeping, cdg, airport-terminals

I will likely have a layover of 13 hours, from 20:45 (evening) to 10:30 (morning) in Paris CDG, flying in from outside the EU. I want to get the closest thing to a full night's sleep, in a bed, in a room, that I can - without burning a hole in my pocket. Let's cap it at, say, 150 EUR, though I would really like it to be no more than half that.

What are my options?

I'll mention I don't even know whether I'm even allowed to exit the terminal (with my carry-on luggage), and go into the city. If that's the case, then I can just look for something in Paris (and no need to recommend one of a million options there of course).

If I am sort-of-stuck, are there arrangements for possibly staying at the airport-neighboring hotels? Are there in-terminal hotels? Or even sleeping booths? I know that those exist in some airports in the world.

Notes:

- I don't need a visa to enter France.
- I'm flying Air France in both legs, and they're being booked together.
- I'm not very fussy about my sleeping accomodations, except for noise and heat.

<sub>A related but less specific question: [Long layover at Charles de Gaulle airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20162/33321) .</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many hotels around CDG, either at Roissypole (reachable on foot from terminal 3) or reachable using shuttles. The [official website](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/services/hotels) has a map and a search form you might use to check rates and availability. The unofficial [easycdg.com](http://easycdg.com/hotels-cdg-airport-de-gaulle/) has another slightly more usable list with some info on hotels shuttle (in total 25 hotels in Roissy are served by shuttles).

If you are willing to use a shuttle, something like Première Classe or Ibis Budget will have bare bones comfort but usually clean modern rooms for €30-50 per night. If you prefer something at Roissypole, Ibis is probably going to be the cheapest and offer rooms around your target of €75 but even the Mercure, CitizenM, or Hilton might have rooms under your upper limit. In any case, all these require you to go landside and leave the terminal.

There is also an hotel *airside*, which therefore does not require you to have the right to enter France or budget any time to go through security and passport control when reentering the airport: the [Yotel Air](https://www.yotel.com/en/hotels/paris-charles-de-gaulle-airport). It is more expensive than cheap landside hotels but still within your price range, you might find that the convenience is worth it.

There is also a Sheraton inside terminal 2 (thus saving you the trip with the people mover and the short walk outside terminal 3) but I don't think it's located airside and it's outside your price range.

Note that there are several Ibis hotels in the vicinity (and actually three distinct Ibis brands with a different price and service level). The one that's *at* the airport (no need to take a shuttle) is [Hôtel ibis Paris CDG Airport](https://www.accorhotels.com/fr/hotel-1404-ibis-paris-cdg-airport/index.shtml), the others are 3 to 5 km away.

Comment: Nice answer, and +1 even just for the last note - which explains why I saw such high rates for (one of the) Hotel Ibis(es).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know there was an airside hotel in CDG. The Sheraton is definitely landslide (above the train station). Note that Roissypole is reachable via the free people mover from both terminals 1 and 2 A/B/C/D/E/F. 2G is a different story.

Answer (score 3):

If you're flying through terminal 2 at CDG there's [Yotel CDG airside](https://www.yotel.com/en/hotels/paris-charles-de-gaulle-airport) which looks like it might be competitive with the hotels in the Roissypole between-the-terminals development that Vincent pointed to.

There's a gaggle of hotels of various price ranges in Roissy-en-France just on the other side of the A1 motorway, but they do not seem to be easily accessible on foot.

Otherwise, since you have plenty-ish of time, fire up Google Maps and look for budget options near the stations on the RER B line towards Paris -- for example, [this](http://www.egghotel.fr/hotel/3/egg-hotel-sevran.html) four stops from the airport.

Comment: I haven't explored it personally but note that Sevran has a rather bad reputation, as do several of the suburbs between CDG and Paris.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Hôtel Ibis inside the airport area near Terminal3.
Easy access and not so expensive.

Comment: Are you sure I'd be able to access it during a layover? Also - it's just barely within the price range I mentioned. Still, +1 for this.

Comment: @einpoklum: The Ibis is close to terminal 3 (300 m by foot) but definitely landside. However, your profile states that you're in The Netherlands, so you must have the right to enter the Schengen area, and there'd be nothing else that prevents you from going there.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Actually I won't be flying from the Netherlands, but I can indeed enter France. And - are you sure nothing will stop me? I mean, I will need to pass border control going _out_ with a ticket suggeting I was only supposed to have a layover. Anyway, this point has inspired me to ask [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121051/layover-within-euschengen-can-i-leave-the-transit-area).

Comment: @einpoklum Who would stop you and on what basis? Who says a layover has to be airside or spending the night in a hotel is not “only a layover”? What if you have a ticket out in 24 hours? 7 days? I usually book trips with day-long layovers (sometimes known as stopovers) on both legs all on the same ticket and that's not an issue at all.

Comment: Ibis does look like one of the cheaper hotels easily accessible from the terminals. If you're not flying to/from terminal 3 the free CDGVAL peoplemover between terminals will get you there (and its T3 station is closer to Ibis than it is to the actual terminal 3!). You can play around on Google Maps to shop for offers from the other hotels in the Roissypole area.

Comment: @einpoklum Hotel Ibis is only barely within EUR150? Eek. I stayed there one time when delays meant I missed a connection. The walls were paper thin so I barely slept, and then the coffee at breakfast at 5am seemed to be decaff. It was definitely at the budget end of the market, though this would have been about 20 years ago.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Maybe it's cheaper if you book a long time in advance. Anyway, there are cheaper options outside CDG, even if they require a bit of travel by public transportation.

Comment: @einpoklum I literally turned up at the front desk and asked "do you have a room for tonight?" Anyway, I'm not disputing your claim, just being very surprised by it.

Comment: Apparently, there are multiple "Hotel Ibis"es at or near CDG, at different levels of price and quality of service - which resolves the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

The dirt-cheap option is Formule 1.  They're a subsidiary of Accord, everything is super-automated (don't forget your credit card!) but it's usually clean and perfectly adequate if all you want is a bed.  There's a bunch of them right around Roissy, very convenient.

Comment: What is Formule 1? Where is it located? Can you post a link?

Comment: google "formule 1 hotel roissy"

Comment: George, on StackExchange sites the policy is that answers include most of the relevant information, without relying on links or outside searches. My comment was just a tip which would allow me to upvote you...

Answer (score 0):

> I'll mention I don't even know whether I'm even allowed to exit the terminal (with my carry-on luggage), and go into the city.

Why wouldn't you be allowed to exit? You have your passport, yes? At the worst, you just have to go thru Customs & Immigrations on the way out, then a Security check on the way back in.

I've not flown to France myself, but I would be surprised if there were more to it.

Comment: "Why wouldn't you be allowed to exit?" I don't have a good answer to that. But - it's not about what is reasonable, it's about the rules, and I'm not sure what they are. Maybe airlines want to charge more for pairs-of-connecting flights rather than a flight-with-a-connection? Maybe they're not willing for you to leave your hold luggage in the airport while you leave it? I just don't know.

Comment: It's not like you can get to your hold luggage until you get to the end destination - you don't get it back and then have to re-check it in, unless maybe you were changing airlines between international carriers. Just leave.  Or call Air France and ask them.

Comment: @CrossRoads: For an overnight layover I think most airlines would be willing to short-check one's bags.

Comment: @einpoklum Airlines cannot and may not prevent you to leave at any point during your journey, certainly not in Europe. They cannot restrain customers to enforce contracts! At most, they may make it difficult to reenter (make sure to get a boarding pass for the second leg) or use the rest of your ticket (as they do when you try things like hidden city ticketing) but not from leaving.